# Windows Task Continues Running Despite UFT Script Completion

Tags: windows, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, taskscheduler

I am trying to create a task that will run a script to launch a UFT (Unified Functional Testing) run on a daily basis. My script correctly launches the UFT run to completion and delivers an exit code that I have verified in Powershell. Here is the VBS script:

```
testResourcePath = "D:\testnow\code\"


'Getting the test path

Dim objArgs

Set objArgs = wscript.Arguments

testPath = objArgs(0)



'Determining that the test does exist

Dim objFSO

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

DoesFolderExist = objFSO.FolderExists(testPath)

Set objFSO = Nothing




If DoesFolderExist Then

    Dim uftApp 'Declare the Application object variable

    Dim uftTest 'Declare a Test object variable

    Set uftApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") 'Create the Application object

    uftApp.Launch 'Start QuickTest

    uftApp.Visible = true 'Make the QuickTest application visible

    'Associating function libraries
    uftApp.Open testPath + "\fakepath", False, False
    Set objLib = uftApp.Test.Settings.Resources.Libraries
    'If the library is not already associated with the test case, associate it..
    If objLib.Find(testPath + "\fakepath\ErrorHandlingLibrary.qfl") = -1 Then ' If library is not already added
        objLib.Add testPath + "\fakepath\ErrorHandlingLibrary.qfl", 1 
        objLib.Add testPath + "\fakepath\ObjectDefinitionLibrary.qfl", 1
        objLib.Add testPath + "\fakepath\TestFunctionLibrary.qfl", 1 
        objLib.Add testPath + "\fakepath\UtilityLibrary.qfl", 1 
    End If

    'uftApp.Open testPath, False 'Open the test in read-only mode

    Set uftTest = uftApp.Test

    Set uftResultsOpt = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions") ' Create the Run Results Options object

    uftResultsOpt.ResultsLocation = testResourcePath ' Specify the location to save the test results.

    uftTest.Run uftResultsOpt,True 'Run the test and wait until end of the test run

    Dim returnCode
    If uftTest.LastRunResults.Status = "Failed" Then
        'qtTest.Run 'Run the test
        uftTest.Close 'Close the test
        returnCode = 1
    Else

        returnCode = 0
    End If
    uftTest.Close 'Close the test
    uftApp.Quit
    WScript.Echo "Closing Test"
Else

    'Couldn't find the test folder. That's bad. Guess we'll have to report on how we couldn't find the test.

    'Insert reporting mechanism here.

End If

WScript.Quit(returnCode)
```

Despite this, the task continues running and I have to manually end the task in Task Scheduler. I am unsure if this is an issue with the script itself or if it is an issue with UFT, I am not familiar enough with either UFT of VBS to tell.

Comment: Per your problem statement, I'm guessing something to do with task scheduler. Can you check the following setting, taskscheduler->yourtask->properties->settings, see if the retry checkbox is enabled.

Comment: When you say task is running, do you mean that UFT doesn't close afer completion ? or the test execution hangs ?